# Configuring puppetdb module in Puppet using Hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera, puppetdb

I'm trying to install the [PuppetDB Module](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/puppetdb).   Part of this bundles a module for installing some requisite Postgres instances which I am using as well.

We primary use heira to configure roles and set various properties.

I have the configuration far enough long that if I add

```
roles:
    - role::postgresql_puppetdb
```

To a hostnames hiera yaml file it will get picked up and get a basic postgres instance pushed out.

I'm stuck on getting specific postgresql.conf variables set.  For example I've tried

```
roles:
   - role::postgresql_puppetdb
      - wal_level: hot_standby
```

However that does get pushed to on subsequent agent run.

I'm hoping someone out there might have gone through trying to model PuppetDB configs in this manner and point out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How exactly is your `roles` array being pulled in and used?  Are you using `hiera_include()` at all or some kind of class declarations in `site.pp` based on what's in `roles`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Puppet to lookup class parameters in Hiera (which it does by default since 3.0.0) these parameters need to be specified as simple key-value pairs, not complex datatypes.

This is how you would specify the `datadir` parameter of the class `postgresql::server` in the `puppetlabs-postgresql` module to point to an alternate data directory for Postgres:

```
# /etc/puppet/hieradata/foo.example.com.yaml
---
# Puppet automatically looks here for parameters when applying the class postgresql::server
postgresql::server::datadir: /srv/postgres/main
```

However, I don't think this is what you need in your case. You want to specify Postgres configuration parameters, for which you need to use the `postgresql::server::config_entry` defined type. There is currently no way to lookup type parameters in Hiera, that only works for class parameters.

So either you parameterize your `role::postgresql_puppetdb` class so you can pass class parameters to it, that in turn get fed into `postgresql::server::config_entry` declarations, or you use the `create_resources()` function together with `hiera_array()` or `hiera_hash()` to look up the Postgres configuration settings you want to apply.

An example for the first approach:

```
class role::postgresql_puppetdb (
  wal_level => 'minimal'
  ...
) {

  class { 'postgresql':
     ...
  }

  class { 'puppetdb':
     ...
  }

  postgresql::server::config_entry { 'wal_level':
    value => $role::postgresql_puppetdb::wal_level
  }
}
```

And then in Hiera.

```
# /etc/puppet/hieradata/foo.example.com.yaml
---
role::postgresql_puppetdb::wal_level: hot_standby
```

This is obviously a bit inflexible as you need to expose every tunable parameter and configuration setting the `postgresql` class provides through your `role::postgresql_puppetdb` class as well. Of course this might be enough for you if you know you only need to expose few tunables like this.

An example for the second approach:

```
class role::postgresql_puppetdb {

  class { 'postgresql':
     ...
  }

  class { 'puppetdb':
     ...
  }

  $postgres_config_entries = hiera_hash('postgres_configs', {})

  create_resources('postgresql::server::config_entry', $postgres_config_entries)

}
```

Then in Hiera:

```
# /etc/puppet/hieradata/foo.example.com.yaml
---
postgres_configs:
  wal_level:
    value: hot_standby
  authentication_timeout:
    value: 120s
  krb_server_keyfile:
    value: /var/lib/postgresql/postgresql.keytab
```

And so on. This is more flexible and allows you to set arbitrary Postgres parameters on every hierarchy level you want. In this case, of course, Hiera will only be consulted for these configuration settings when the `role::postgresql_puppetdb` class is included, but nothing keeps you from putting that hiera_hash-create_resources combo in other roles, possibly a `role::postgresql`.

I hope this was understandable and coherent enough to follow. The above is of course untested like posted, but we use this very strategy (create_resources, hiera_hash) to manage local and system accounts, repos, sudoers rules, Tomcat instances and others. Will revisit the question tomorrow when I am less tired.

But do have a look at this excellent question on Puppet-Ask: https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/1655/an-end-to-end-roleprofile-example-using-hiera/

It walks through a similar setup based on HAproxy. Very useful to understand.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I gave this a shot but I seem to be getting a "Error 400 on SERVER: can't convert Fixnum into Hash at " error during an agent run.  It's pointing to a line number for the create_resources call

Comment: Nevermind, it was a problem with a typo in my yaml definition.